# How to show fields from different table through foreign key and natural key in django query statement

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In mysql if you want to get some fields in different tables the query qould be like this

```
`select tab1.field, tab2.field1, tab3.fieldA from CustomerOrder tab1, Food tab2, table3 tab3, table4 tab4 where tab1.id=tab2.tab1_id and tab2.id=tab4.tab3_id and tab3.id=tab4.tab3_idx`
```

This query would help you get the field stated above.
I have tried to do the same thing in django but it is giving me the number instead of the field_name it e.g. instead of Burrito
for tab2.field1 it is sending me id number 15

CustomerOrder   is table1
Food        is table2
CustomerAddress is table3

CustomerOrder is my entry point

```
CustomerOrder.objects.filter(customer=customername)
```

These are my models

```
class CustomerOrderManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, customer, food, customeraddress):
        return self.get( customer=customer, food=food, customeraddress=customeraddress, ) 
    
#this contains the subject a students registered for in a specific customeraddress
class CustomerOrder(models.Model):
    customer  = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    customeraddress = models.ForeignKey(CustomerAddress, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    objects = CustomerOrderManager()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['customer','food','customeraddress']]
        
    #**** when i use this it prevents the pk or id from showing when i save a customerorder
    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.customer, self.food, self.customeraddress)

        

class FoodManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, food_type, food_name, description):
        return self.get(food_type=food_type, food_name=food_name, 
                    description=description)
class Food(models.Model):
    food_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    food_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    objects = FoodManager()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['food_type', 'food_name', 'description']]
    
    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.food_type, self.food_name, self.description)
    

class CustomerManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self,customer_name):
        return self.get(customer_name=customer_name)

class CustomerAddress(models.Model):
    food_type  = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    customer_name  = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    order_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    objects = CustomerManager()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['customer_name']]
    
    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.customer_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do?

It will give you all the fields of CustomerOrder plus two additional fields named 'customer_name' and 'food_name'.  PS: make sure you import F. `from django.db.models import F`

`CustomerOrder.objects.filter(customer=customername).all().annotate(customer_name=F('customer__name'), food_name=F('food__food_name'))`

I'm not sure about customer_address, I dont see any 'address' field in your models. You can traverse it using double underscores '__' from FK field in your calling model (CustomerOrder in this example)

Comment: I am very gr8ful, I would work on it and grt back to you.

Comment: @SMev sure! Tag me in the comments if this doesn't work

Comment: I Thanks for the help I tried it but it did not work, is there anything wrong in the models itself? I belive that I have done everything right in the model declaration

Comment: @SMev is it throwing an error? it should return 'customer_name' and 'food_name', what results are you getting in your queryset?

Comment: the query is producing fields from CustomerOrder only, instead of producing fields from others such as Food it produces the number or id e.g. 15 instead of Burrito. Sorry for the late response I had to continue with other parts of the project

Comment: @SMev You mean even annotation is returning food id? are you accessing 'food_name' or something else after running annotation queryset?

Comment: thank it worked I made a mistake in syntax